# Return image from exe

Tags: c#

I have an exe (i have the code for that exe) where i invoke the camera.
Now i want the image captured in my application(ie..the picturebox control)
I am ivoking that exe in my application(the application is in vb script).
Can we return image from exe to my application(the application is in vb script)...
if yes how?

Comment: You have the code for that exe, how is the image captured? Is it saved somewhere?

Comment: yes it is saved in some folder

Comment: Then load the image from the folder. Use vbscript filesystemobject object.

Comment: if it's not clear which file in the folder is it, you could have the exe return the file path via stdout (Console.WriteLine, for instance) and then the vbscript reads the output of the exe to get the path, then reads the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to code, why not put it in the application that you want the image in?

If that is not possible, save the image file to location on the drive and then monitor it using a FileSystemWatcher control.  Once you have retrieved the file from the location and processed it you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a file location to (temprarily) store the images, and configure that path in both applications.

Another option would be to use WCF (or COM) to let the camera app act as a server