# How to return value from exe and capture the returned value using C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have an exe (I have the C# code for that also). I am invoking the exe
 in my vbscript application. Then I want to return a value from the exe and 
 capture the value in my vbscript code.  How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return image from exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964388/return-image-from-exe)

Comment: why have you created a new account and asked virtually an identical question to what you asked yesterday?

Comment: @slugster: I think he's trying to implement one of the suggestions (from the comments: "have the exe return the file path via stdout and then the vbscript reads the output of the exe to get the path, then reads the file. – James Manning"). I'd say it's different enough ("what are my options in passing data between two programs"/"how to implement one of the options").

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("csharpprocess.exe")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExec.ExitCode
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28VS.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za76z6hh%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To return a number from the EXE file, set this value in your C# code before you exit it.

```
Environment.ExitCode = MyNumber;
```